# ¿Por qué no se quitan del caché de la app movil, los datos borrados en mi firebase, si estoy usando persistencia?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, realtime-database

Hola soy nueva programando en Android studio, estoy haciendo una appmovil con una base de datos en firabase, para que pueda trabajar sin internet uso persistencia pero por alguna razon los datos que borro directamente de mi base de datos siguen estando en la app movil, por ejemplo si en mi app tengo una lista de nombre y borro un nombre directamente de la base de datos, este nombre sigue aparenciendo en la app, sin embargo si este objeto lo borro desde la app si desaparece al cargar los datos.
Para la persistencia hago una clase que extiende de application y esta la declaro en el manifest como nombre de la applicación, este es el codigo de la clase:

```
public class HolcimQuarry extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Por ultimo solo hago un keepSynced(true) a cada referencia.

Answer (score 0):

> para que pueda trabajar sin internet uso persistencia pero por alguna
> razon los datos que borro directamente de mi base de datos siguen
> estando en la app movil,

Los datos guardados mediante persistencia son guardados en una archivo que no tiene relación con la base de datos de tu aplicación, es por esta razón que estos pueden permanecer.

Es importante la persistencia es en realidad [persistencia en disco](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?hl=es#section-disk-persistence)

> [Persistencia en disco](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?hl=es#section-disk-persistence) Las apps de Firebase controlan las
> interrupciones temporales de red de manera automática. Los datos
> almacenados en caché están disponibles sin conexión y Firebase vuelve
> a enviar todas las operaciones de escritura cuando se restablece la
> conectividad de red.

> Cuando habilitas la persistencia en disco, la app escribe los datos de
> manera local en el dispositivo para poder mantener el estado mientras
> está sin conexión, incluso si el usuario o el sistema operativo la
> reinician.

los valores guardados en una persistencia son valores clave-valor de tipos de datos primitivos en el sistema de archivos de Android, estos son guardados en un archivo que en realidad es un .xml en disco, si se elimina caché, esta información es eliminada.